# How can I have multiple lines in a header or footer using scrpage2?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

For an assignment at university I have to copy a lay-out template that is provided in Word but I want to use LaTeX. For this, I need to have two lines in the footer.

How can I achieve this using scrpage2? It is possible to simply use `\\` in the text, e.g.

```
\refoot{\upshape Course year\\ 2010/2011}
```

however, then the text is shifted upwards into my separation line instead of downwards.

There are the commands

```
\setheadwidth
\setfootwidth
```

available but not

```
\setfootheight
\setheadheight
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[headsepline, footsepline]{scrpage2}

\refoot{Course year\\ 2010/2011} 
\rofoot{Course year\\ 2010/2011}

\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
 This is a sample document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added a minimal example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in LaTeX2e the command `\footheight` does not longer exist. It actually did in LaTeX 2.09.
To solve your problem there are two possible options.

1) You can use `\raisebox` and e.g. a tabular environment to get everything below the line

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage[headsepline, footsepline]{scrpage2}

\refoot{Course year\\ 2010/2011} 
\rofoot{\raisebox{-5ex}{\begin{tabular}[t]{rr}
Course year\\
2010/2011
\end{tabular}}}

\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

 This is a sample document.
\end{document}
```

2) or you draw the line yourself with `\rule`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}

\refoot{Course year\\ 2010/2011} 
\rofoot{%
\rule{1\textwidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{rr}
Course year\\
2010/2011
\end{tabular}}

\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

 This is a sample document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked indeed. I know that typographically, this solution is horrible. But what can you do about stupid university requirements...?

Answer (score 4):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.12 there is a `footheight` option defined. Package `scrlayer-scrpage` (the successor of `scrpage2`) takes this option into account:

```
\documentclass[
  footheight=30pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ofoot{Course year\\ 2010/2011}

\begin{document}
 This is a sample document.
\end{document}
```

[image]